# Adding components over image

Tags: java, swing, components

I've been looking all over the internet for a solution of how to add components over image. I've tried this:

```
    setContentPane(new JComponent(){
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            URL url = ...;
            if(url==null){
                //... Irelevant
                return;
            }
            try {
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
                g.drawImage(img,0 ,0, this);
                super.paintComponents(g);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //... Irelevant
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

        }
    });
    nameLabel=new JLabel("<html><body>"+Main.translateColorsToHTML(name)+"</body></html>");
    nameLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    nameLabel.setVisible(true);
    add(nameLabel);
```

Which didn't work, so I've tried this:

```
    URL url = ...;//Fetching the url
    if(url==null){
        //... Unrelevant
        return;
    }
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        invImg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        invImg.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(340, 250));
        setContentPane(invImg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

And then adding a component to the content pane / the frame itself.
I have absoloutly no idea how to do this, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try painting the images AFTER you call `super.paintComponent`, which should always be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works just fine:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
invImg = new JLabel();
invImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
invImg.setLayout(new BoxLayout(invImg, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
setContentPane(invImg);
```

Comment: The problem with using a `JLabel` this way is the label won't honour the preferred size of the child components, but will only honour the requirements of the image/text properties of the label itself

Answer (score 0):

Hey mind to add a `jPanel` on your `JFrame` ? (It is almost always a better idea)

Add a `jPanel` on your `JFrame` , and draw on it.

`Override` the `paint(Graphics2D g)` method of `jPanel` (inherited from `JComponent`) and draw your image like this

```
yourPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                g.drawImage(yourImage, null, x, y);
            }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and for some reason it didn't work. Anyways, I found a solution. Thanks anyways!